# Select Command Where a field must equal a value but another field can have 2 values

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT users.user_id,
       users.first_name,
       users.last_name,
       roles.role,
       roles.role_id,
       users.username,
       users.description,
       users_vs_teams.team_id,
       teams.team_name,
       teams.status,
       teams.notes
FROM teams
     INNER JOIN users_vs_teams ON teams.team_id = users_vs_teams.team_id
     RIGHT OUTER JOIN users ON users_vs_teams.user_id = users.user_id
     INNER JOIN roles ON users.role_id = roles.role_id 
WHERE( users.role_id = 3 ) AND ( teams.status = 'Completed' ) OR ( teams.status IS NULL )
```

I want to display only users with a `role_id` of `3` but `team.status` can be either `Completed` or `NULL`. However, this query displays all roles where `teams.status` is either `Completed` or `NULL`. Any help resolving this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have an incorrect joining in your `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`, you dont have joining ids , some lang `ON some_id = some_id`

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm not sure if you need an outer join for this.  Second, your problem seems to be parentheses in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.first_name, u.last_name, r.role, r.role_id,
       u.username, u.description, uvt.team_id, 
       t.team_name, t.status, t.notes
FROM teams t INNER JOIN
     users_vs_teams uvt
     ON t.team_id = uvt.team_id  INNER JOIN
     users u 
     ON uvt.user_id = u.user_id
     roles r
     ON u.role_id = r.role_id ON u
WHERE (u.role_id = 3) AND (t.status = 'Completed' OR t.status IS NULL)
```

Note that table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` and fix your parenthesis in your `WHERE clause`.

```
SELECT users.user_id,
       users.first_name,
       users.last_name,
       roles.role,
       roles.role_id,
       users.username,
       users.description,
       users_vs_teams.team_id,
       teams.team_name,
       teams.status,
       teams.notes
FROM teams
     INNER JOIN users_vs_teams ON teams.team_id = users_vs_teams.team_id
     INNER JOIN users ON users_vs_teams.user_id = users.user_id
     INNER JOIN roles ON users.role_id = roles.role_id 
WHERE( users.role_id = 3 ) AND ( teams.status = 'Completed' OR teams.status IS NULL)
```

you can also do something like this:

```
    ( teams.status = 'Completed' OR ISNULL(teams.status,'') = '')
```